# $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = 1$, not $0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, totient-function

Let $\varphi(n) = \sharp\{1\leq x \leq n : (x,n) = 1\}$.  Then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = 1$.   My attempt: $\inf_{k\geq n}\frac{\varphi(k)}{k} \leq 1$ since for $n = 2$, this infimum equals $1$, we have that $\sup_{n\geq 1} \inf_{k\geq n} \frac{\varphi(k)}{k} = 1$.

Okay, that proof didn't work because $\varphi(2)/2 = 0.5$, but letting $n = 1$, we have $\varphi(1)/1 = 1$.  QED

Is that correct?  Then my book is wrong:

[Probabilistic Number Theory by Dr.J¨orn Steuding (page 4)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111222233654/http://hdebruijn.soo.dto.tudelft.nl/jaar2004/prob.pdf)

Comment: Do you know what lim inf means? Tell us what you think it means.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I used another definition of it.

Comment: Least upper bound of the minimum of the tail of a sequence.

Comment: You use lim inf to denote an upper bound?

Comment: lim inf is the limit of greatest lower bounds on tails. You have lim inf and lim sup backwards.

Comment: Most relevantly, changing _any_ finite number of values of a function won't change its lim inf.  And so in particular, examining any finite number of values can't possibly tell you the lim inf.

Comment: I don't see how I'm doing this backwards, please answer in a post.  I used the Wikipedia definition and I've proved basic properties of these before.  I double checked that I'm doing this correctly.  How weird...

Comment: I'll use it right now: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{Blue}{\inf_{k\ge n}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{Blue}{0}=0.$$

Comment: It says right there next to it the definition I used!  What is going on, are you not seeing it?

Comment: You mean $\sup_{n\ge1}\inf_{k\ge n}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}$? Even that is $0$, because $\inf_{k\ge n}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how you get that it equals 0.

Comment: Infimum is the greatest lower bound. Since $\phi(k)/k$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ (just make $k$ a product of the $m$ primes, and let $m\to\infty$) but $\phi(k)/k>0$ always, the greatest lower bound is $0$, no matter how many initial values of $\phi(k)/k$ we exclude.

Comment: Thanks.  I see where I went wrong there. :D

Comment: There is no such thing as the minimum of the tail of the sequence unless you have proven it! In general it does not even exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $l \in \mathbb{R}$. Then it can be shown that $l = \liminf_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, i) there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $\inf_{n \geq N}a_{n} > l-\varepsilon$ and ii) for every $N \geq 1$ there is some $n \geq N$ such that $a_{n} < l + \varepsilon$.

Let $a_{n} := \varphi(n)/n$ for all $n \geq 1$. We claim that $\liminf a_{n} = 0$. Since $a_{n} > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$, Property i) holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$. But because of the prime form of $a_{n}$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $a_{n} < \varepsilon$ for large $n$, and Property ii) follows.

Thus $\liminf a_{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

About lim inf, if we can provide a sequence of numbers $n$ such that $\phi(n)/n$ goes to zero, then your liminf is, in fact, zero.

The sequence we use is the primorials, the products of the consecutive primes up to some bound. So, the sequence is $$ 2,6,30, 210,\ldots $$

If $$ N = \prod_{p \leq x} p $$ for some postive real $x,$ then 
$$ \frac{\phi(N)}{N} = \prod_{p \leq x} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right).  $$
As $x \rightarrow \infty,$ this product goes to $0.$ Taking logarithms, this follows from the fact that the harmonic sum of the primes diverges. Indeed, for $x > 1,$ from Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962), (3.26) on page 70, we have
$$ \frac{\phi(N)}{N} = \prod_{p \leq x} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) < \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2 \log^2 x} \right).  $$
Here $\gamma = 0.5772156649...$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Anyway why did you say $\limsup$ when you're doing $\liminf$ (of a non-negative sequence)?

Comment: @user21820, thanks, corrected.

Comment: Alternatively, since $\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{p}=\lim_{p\to\infty} \, \ln\big(\ln(p)\big)$ diverges, $\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=0$.  Hence, $\frac{\phi(p\#)}{p\#}\to 0$ as $p\to\infty$.

Comment: @Batominovski, yes, i briefly indicated that with the sentence "Taking logarithms..." but could not recall whether divergence of the harmonic sum of primes preceded Merten's theorem.